# Eclipse Auto Code completion method selection not showing super class methods

Tags: eclipse, code-completion

My Eclipse Junos only shows the methods of the current class on Ctrl+Space but is missing the methods inherited from super classes in one of my Projects (It did work until like 5 minutes ago and does work in other projects/ eclipse instances). Any suggestions?

**Solved**

Turns out there is the possibility to have certain packages excluded from beeing proposed in the Open-Types/ Method selection and i somehow managed to get "java.*" added to that.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist then under "Sorting and Filtering" there is the link "type filters" which opens the dialog to configure above mentioned exclusions.

Comment: You could post your own solution into a separate answer and accept it! :) This way you could also get upvotes for that and the question is separated from the answer (which is the common practice here).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Content assist provides a list of suggested completions for partially entered strings. In the editor pane press Ctrl+Space or use Edit > Content Assist.
For more details, check 
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html

Comment: I am aware of that :) It just happened that there was nothing else displayed but the methods from the current class

Comment: Does pressing Ctrl+T help to switch to the Supertype hierarchy?

Comment: I was already able to solve the issue (see above "Solution"). I somehow managed to exclude the entire java.* classes from Ctrl+T and Ctrl+Space functionality o.O

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the autocomplete with `com.sun.jersey`. After removing the filter `on com.sun.*`, it's now working again.